# LiveStreams: list empty result

Tags: youtube-livestreaming-api

I'm testing YouTube live streaming API using Java client libraries.

I have a simple project which is basically the copy of ListStreams example taken from here:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/code_samples/java#retrieve_a_channel_s_live_video_streams.

I have my application registered in Google developers console. I have created a test public live stream and a test broadcast.
Everything works fine, I can broadcast video from my phone to this live stream.

But when I try to get a list of live streams from my channel I always get an empty result.

The funny thing is that I can successfully retrieve my channel's broadcasts using the LiveBroadcasts.java example.

But no matter what I do the list of streams is always empty.

Did anyone have similar problems ?

Cheers, Dmitry.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please note, that this is not a free code-writing service, but we are eager to help fellow programmers (and aspirants) writing their own code. Please read the help topics on [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Afterwards, please update your question with the code you have written thus far in order to complete the task(s) you wish to achieve.

Comment: Have you found why ? Hit the same problem here